# Failed to fetch ppa - cannot update anymore

Tags: apt, updates, ssh, ppa

I can't update my machine anymore.

To me it seems I have the problem that my machine doesn't accept the package signatures. However I have no idea how to solve it, any help would be appreciated.

`Software Updater` complains with: 
Failed to download repository information - Check your Internet connection. -> While I have internet.

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
...
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial/main 
amd6 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 45.2 kB in 19s (2,289 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable 
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the 
public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable 
InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/font-manager/staging/ubuntu 
xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified 
because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F738B17DF9E284B7
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/font- 
manager/staging/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository 
is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/budgie-remix/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The 
following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is 
not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B139A1EF422D205
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu 
xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/budgie- 
remix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures 
couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY 3B139A1EF422D205
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris- 
lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not 
Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old 
ones used instead.
```

As suggested by comment I followed the URL:

- http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode - not signed (I downloaded it together with anaconda) -> url doesn't exist
- http://ppa.launchpad.net/font-manager/staging/ubuntu xenial There seems to be a `0.7.3~201712020419~ubuntu16.04.1` version
- http://ppa.launchpad.net/budgie-remix/ppa/ubuntu - there is ./dists/xenial/Release (I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for)
- http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu - I couldn't find the xenial/Release file

I'm sorry but I'm still a bit unsure what I'm exactly looking for as my experience with the package manager is quite limited. As it is right now I can't update any package (for example the ones in canonical).

Comment: Did you check to see if those PPAs really have Xenial packages? Simply follow the URLs....