# Upgrade to 18.04 repository info

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

When I try to upgrade to 18.40 from 17.10, I get "Failed to download repository information"  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which repo ? I am guessing a ppa - See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036555/failed-to-fetch-ppa-cannot-update-anymore or similar.

Comment: Not sure which repo.   Probably whatever repo is needed  for 18.40